# Cloud Function with Multiple Triggers - Scheduled and onCall

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that I would like to run whenever a user performs a set of actions on the web app AND daily at a specified time. In the interest of not duplicating code and future features/bug fixes, I'd like to run both from one function/file.

Any suggestions/references on this flow would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your business logic in one function, that you call from the two Cloud Functions. Something along the following lines, with an asynchronous business logic and the use of `async/await`:

```
exports.myFunctionCalledFromTheApp = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const result = await asyncBusinessLogic();
        return { result: result }
    } catch (error) {
        // ...
    }
});

exports.myFunctionCalledByScheduler = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun(async (context) => {
    try {
        await asyncBusinessLogic();
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
});


async function asyncBusinessLogic() {
    
    const result = await anAsynchronousJob();
    return result;
    
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Fantastic. Then I suppose I move the calling user validation/permissions check into the myFunctionCalledFromTheApp? Would be nice to have the context aspect inside of asyncBusineesLogic...

Comment: You can very well pass the `context` object to the `asyncBusinessLogic()` function, but be aware that the `auth` object will only be populated for the Callable Function, not the scheduled one (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#optional-auth). It's up to you to manage the two different cases.

Comment: Thanks a ton! So how can I validate that the scheduled function has 'admin' privledges without exposing the onCall? Just ```!context.auth``` seems unsafe?

Comment: You could identify the caller function by using a parameter, e.g. `async function asyncBusinessLogic(context, caller);` and `await asyncBusinessLogic(context, 'callable');` and `await asyncBusinessLogic(context, 'scheduled');`

Comment: Following my last comment I would deal with the `auth` in the Callable function, in order to decouple the `asyncBusinessLogic`funvtion from the CFs.

Comment: Right on! Thank you