# Firebase "onCreate" function not triggered by Firestore document (re)creation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Firebase function that gets triggered by Firestore document creation (onCreate() triggered).

In same cases, I need that same function to run again, on the same document. Since that function is pretty long, and I don't want to copy it, I elected to trigger it in hacky way:

1. copy the document in a temp collection
2. delete the original document
3. copy again the document with the same *DocumentId* with the data from the copy in its original place
4. delete the copy

This whole thing is done through a Transaction - I guess everything is done AT ONCE in the background.

Since Step 3 uses the SET ( *Transaction.set()* ) method. Why isn't it trigerring the onCreate() event?

Any help or alternative to my situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Since that function is pretty long, and I don't want to copy it," => What do you exactly mean by that? You don't want to copy the Cloud Function code?

Comment: I don't want to create a copy of the function with a trigger other than onCreate(). For example, to repeat the same process, I thought about creating a copy of the function and triggering it through an HTTP when it's needed. But I'd rather not do that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66424744/3371862 you can share some code between several Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I'll consider that. This could be really useful in many cases, not just this one.

Comment: Glad I could help you! You may upvote the answer if it helped you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my own.

For some reason, doing one transaction that deletes the document, then creates it again, the onCreate() event is not triggered.

I ended up splitting the transaction into two parts. Transaction #1 copies the document in a temporary collection then delete the original. Transaction #2 reads the copy, writes the original document in its original collection, with its original DocumentId, and then deletes the temporary copy.

This way, there are a few milliseconds between the delete and create operation of a document, and they are not bundled in the same transaction.

This solved it. Even though I still don't get why the onCreate() event won't trigger by a Document Creation operation that is inside one Transaction.